# Problems with PyDictionary/BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, macos, beautifulsoup, macos-sierra

I am running Python 3 on macOS Sierra and need to create sentences made up of synonyms of specific words. To do this, I am using PyDictionary.

However, when running my code (given below) I get an error (Python interpreter) and a warning (BeautifulSoup).

**Output:**

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/beautifulsoup4-4.5.3-py3.5.egg/bs4/__init__.py:181: UserWarning: No parser was e
xplicitly specified, so I'm using the best available HTML parser for this system ("html.parser"). This usually isn't a problem, but if you run this code on an
other system, or in a different virtual environment, it may use a different parser and behave differently.

The code that caused this warning is on line 53 of the file main.py. To get rid of this warning, change code that looks like this:

 BeautifulSoup([your markup])

to this:

 BeautifulSoup([your markup], "html.parser")

  markup_type=markup_type))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 53, in <module>
    edison()
  File "main.py", line 29, in edison
    say(respond(["I", "am", "happy", "to", "hear", "that", "html.parser"]) + "!")
  File "/path/to/code/respond.py", line 9, in respond
    output = (output + " " + (random.choice(dictionary.synonym(word, "html.parser"))))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/random.py", line 265, in choice
    return seq[i]
KeyError: 0
```

**main.py:**

```
from respond import *


def edison():
    mood = input("Hi, " + username + "! How are you today? ")
    if mood.lower() in definitions.positive:
        print(respond(["I", "am", "happy", "to", "hear", "that", "html.parser"]) + "!") #This is line 29
    elif mood.lower() in definitions.negative:
        print(respond(["I", "am", "sorry", "to", "hear", "that", "html.parser"]) + "!")



edison() #This is line 53
```

**respond.py:**

```
import random
from PyDictionary import PyDictionary
dictionary = PyDictionary()

def respond(wordList):
    output = ""
    for word in wordList:
        output = (output + " " + (random.choice(dictionary.synonym(word, "html.parser"))))
    return output
```

Comment: Why on earth would it have beautiful soup in the error? Did you not include something?

Comment: I'm not using BeautifulSoup myself - however according to the Python Package Index PyDictionary uses it. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyDictionary

Answer (score 0):

I have found exactly your same question but it was solved at https://github.com/VitaliyRodnenko/geeknote/issues/305

Maybe try going to that and I am sure you will find your answer. I cannot directly help you because I do not do PyDictionary but I hope you find your answer. 
I hope it helps.

Comment: Looking at the answer first resented, I don't have anything referring to BeautifulSoup directly in my code, and I would rather not change the source code of PyDictionary. Is there another answer you were referring to?

Comment: No. Sorry. This was the only thing I could find.